# how to show multiple records from database in html table

Tags: php, sql

I want to show multiple records from database upon some criteria in to html table, I only get 1 record, but I have 2 records in database which meet the criteria.

Please help to display all records from database which meets the criteria.

```php
<?php
$count = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM  career group by pno";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pno = $row['pno'];
    $query = "SELECT sum(duration) as total_duration FROM career where pno = $pno";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $Value = $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $total_value = implode(",", $Value);

    if ($total_value < 54) {
        continue;
    }
    $rank_query = "SELECT name,pno,rank,medical_category,staff_course_isc FROM user_general_info where pno = $pno and rank in ('manager','staff') and medical_category = 'Aye' and staff_course_isc = 'Yes'";
    echo $rank_query;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $rank_query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $pno = $row['pno'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];

    // $total_value= implode(",", $Value['name']);
    // echo $total_value; exit;
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($pno); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($name); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($rank); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $count++;
} ?>
```

Here is my database rows

```
Record 1 : Pno: 2222, name: test1, rank : manger , medical_category: Aye : duration : 59, staff_course_isc: Yes 

Record 2 : Pno: 4301234, name:test2, rank : staff , medical_category: Aye : duration : 122, staff_course_isc: Yes
```

Comment: What's the table content? Are you sure that both entries are not filtered out by `if ($total_value < 54)`?

Comment: yes i am sure,

i have 2 rows with Pno (primary key) 2222, 4301234

when i run above query in phpmyadmin it returns 2 rows for 2222, 4301234 but in actual web it only show record for 2222. i think i have an issue with my loop.

Please assist

Comment: Please add the full table content for the two rows you mentioned to the question.

Comment: Record 1 : Pno: 2222, name: test1, rank : manger , medical_category: Aye : duration : 59,  staff_course_isc: Yes

Record 1 : Pno: 4301234, name:test2, rank : staff , medical_category: Aye : duration : 122,  staff_course_isc: Yes

Comment: Please add it in a formatted manner to the question.

Comment: @ Markus Deibel  please check, question edited

Comment: I haven't looked at this in detail, but my guess is that the issue is you are reusing the $result variable within your loop and this interferes with the while condition. Try calling the inner variable something else, such as $result2.

Comment: Dear Steve, i try $result2 but same issue it only showing one record
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your variables differently:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM  career group by pno";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
{
    $pno = $row['pno'];

    $query = "SELECT sum(duration) as total_duration FROM career where pno = $pno";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $Value = $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    $total_value = implode(",", $Value);

    if ($total_value < 54) continue;
    $rank_query = "SELECT name,pno,rank,medical_category,staff_course_isc FROM user_general_info where pno = $pno and rank in ('manager','staff') and medical_category = 'Aye' and staff_course_isc = 'Yes'";
    echo $rank_query;
    $result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $rank_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

    $pno = $row['pno'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];

    // $total_value= implode(",", $Value['name']);
    // echo $total_value; exit;
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($pno); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($name); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($rank); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $count++;
} ?>
```

Comment: This is along the lines I was thinking in my comment on the OP. Will be interested to see the response.